# how to prevent any service to bind to a given interface?

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking

I need to set up a server (preferably RedHat/CentOS/Fedora but the Debian family would work out as well) with no services available on a given interface.

I cannot use `iptables` (which would be the simplest solution).

I could check which ones are enabled and either disable them by hand or force a bind to another interface but there is a risk that after an update/upgrade/additional soft installation the changes would be reverted or an extra service deployed.

Is there a way to configure a network interface so that it does not allow any service to bind to it, so that there is no port listening on it?

Comment: Sure: configure it down.  But I suspect that's not what you mean, is it?  You want the interface up and operating, but without anyone allowed to bind to it.  `iptables` would be much the easiest way to do this; why can you not use it?

Comment: @MadHatter: right, I want it to be up :) One of the main reasons is that we have a scanner which will have issues with iptables (and with firewalls in general).

Comment: A scanner?  Do you mean a device that makes digital images of printed matter?  Or a network scanner?  If the latter, what sort of issues do you think it's likely to have?

Comment: A network scanner. We are likely to face drops from the firewall if we go for an aggressive scan (following a discussion with one of the developers) so I would prefer to go for an iptables-less setup before diving into troubleshooting, should some issues arise (we already probably had a few of these). I am also curious about the existence of such setting :)

Comment: I don't have any idea what you mean by "*we are likely to face drops from the firewall if we go for an aggressive scan*".  How do you think an `iptables` firewall set to send TCP resets to NEW inbound connections will differ from simply having no listening daemon, and the kernel sending TCP resets?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. The risk I want to avoid is to have `iptables` getting overwhelmed during the aggressive scan and not serve (drop) outbound connections (initiated by the scanner). This may or may not be the case, I could also reduce the number of scans in parallel -- the point is that if there is a way to inhibit the binding for one given interface which is in a 'risky' network I would not need though potential troubleshooting. If there is no such setting and the only way is to either go service by service (with the risk I mentioned) or via `iptables`, I will do that.

Comment: Just interesting. What a profit of such interface? How do you plan to use It?

Comment: @Veniamin: I will scan a rogue network through it (so I want to be sure it does not have any services listening)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I finally understand the problem. Main misunderstanding of me (and I suppose some others) was I suggested that a scanner is somewhere outside.

If you plan to use this host as a scanner than iptables may be really overwhelmed.

If so, you need some setup protecting host applications but not creating session records for the scanner traffic.

The solution is simple: create a container (LXC or OpenVZ) and hide your scanner staff there. Use a bridged connection setup of your container to the real network.

Thus your scanner will have a dedicated IP address and host applications will never bind It. In basic setup container's traffic will skip iptables.

If you want to additionally protect the container, turn on iptable lookup for the bridge (`net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1` in sysctl.conf) and add the rules as follow:

```
-I FORWARD -p ip -s <rogue_network> -d <scanner_ip>    -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -p ip -s <scanner_ip>    -d <rogue_network> -j ACCEPT
-I FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

**UPD**:
Previous is not working properly - forget to disable connection tracking:

```
-t raw -I PREROUTING -p ip -s <rogue_network> -d <scanner_ip>    -j NOTRACK
-t raw -I PREROUTING -p ip -s <scanner_ip>    -d <rogue_network> -j NOTRACK
-t raw -I PREROUTING -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
```

Comment: This is a very interesting solution. I will look closely look at that. Thanks!

Comment: @WoJ You are wellcome. Moving "solution check" was very anticipatory. Not yet sure, it is really working. As well as there may be more other solutions around stateless firewall setup with disabled connection tracking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way to tell the kernel not to allow binding to a given network interface.  You say that you'll consider `iptables`, so for my money having the line

```
iptables -I INPUT 1 -p tcp -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
```

will have the same effect (for daemons binding to TCP ports) as simply not having a daemon bound; in both cases a TCP reset will be issued.  Similarly, the line

```
iptables -I INPUT 2 -p udp -m state --state NEW -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

will do the same thing for new connections to UDP ports as having no listener bound: the kernel will emit an ICMP port-unreachable packet in either case.

This is an extremely simple `iptables` setup, and is unlikely to be overwhelmed by any amount of traffic that you can put through that NIC.

Comment: Since there are apparently no mechanisms to deny the binding I will go for iptables :(

Comment: @WoJ You really do not have reasons to worry about. Iptables can be  overwhelmed if connections are allowed, tracked and recorded in the connection table. A setup such this does not do It. So, overhead is approximately as no iptables at all.